# Where is dotnetconfig45.xsd

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I need to make some changes to the intellisense schema for .net 4.5, but I can't find it.

the others are all available in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas

but not 4.5

Does anyone know how to adjust the 4.5 schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration for .NET 4.5 is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\DotNetConfig.xsd`.

Comment: Not if you've got VS Express